# Is nesting objects considered good practice?

Tags: javascript

Is nesting objects and calling them such as var1.var2.func1(); generally ok for performance and coding practice? There are alternatives but is this method acceptable?

```
function foo(name) {
  this.bar = {
      xyz: function() {
          console.log(name)
      }
  }
}

var abc = new foo("John");

abc.bar.xyz();
```

Comment: Why not? Why can't you do that?

Comment: I'm a bit new to javascript so I was wondering if nesting objects was a standard.

Comment: That just looks like plain ol' code encapsulation...

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly fine; you have to be careful with `this` in these nested functions. `this` is a bit odd in JS, compared to what you might be used to. That's not a problem in general, but you should be aware of the quirks of `this` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I can see with the code above is that it violates the Law of Demeter or Principle of least knowledge.

You can read more about this design guideline here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: Depends on whether you treat `bar` as part of the public interface or not, and what `xyz` exactly does.